# ReactJs cannot access props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to access the props in my child component, I am rendering a grid row using a mapped json result:

```
getRowNodes: function() {
    return this.props.contacts.map(function(contact){
        return <Row 
                key={contact.id} 
                contact={contact} 
                columns={this.props.children} />;
    }.bind(this));
}
```

When I render the component I can console log {this.props.data} and see all the properties, I can also see all the properties in chrome dev tools, however, when I try and access a property this.props.data.propertyName I get undefined.

If I try and access any of the properties below I get an error..any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Documentation says React.js can render only single node. If there are multiple nodes they should be wrapped into one root

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like *Kirill Slatin* said: You have to wrap it.

Try this:

```
getRowNodes() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.contacts.map(this._getRow)}
        </div>
    );
},

_getRow(contact) {
    return (
        <Row 
            key={contact.id}
            contact={contact}
            columns={this.props.children} />
    );
}
```

> **NOTE**: I have optimized the readability by using JSX Syntax.