# Reactjs access Object property from JSON in Child companent using props

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Might be duplicate of [ReactJs cannot access props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31132170/reactjs-cannot-access-props) but this didn't help me still getting undefined.

But i am stuck with syntax how to **fetch** a **object property** eg : object "releasedata"s "**name**" property in the below JSON response using props in React in my child component.

Please Note : Not an array which i found lots of answer in stack.

JSON :

```
{
    id: "-559674239450219239",
    key: "TASK-1",
    name: "Hide old Releases",
    projectId: "-5010744238007635986",
    releasedata: {
        releaseId: "508054512004262880",
        name: "prog rel1",
        projectId: null,
        programId: "1",
    },
    done: false,
};
```

My Code :

Parent :

```
componentDidMount: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/app/restapi/getreleasedata/"+Key+"?access_token="+accesstokenvalue+""
        }).then(function(data) {
             this.setState({data: data});
                      console.log(data);
            }.bind(this))
    },
render: function(){
    return (
            <PbiHeader releaseData={this.state.data.releasedata}  />                
    )
  }
});
```

Child Component :

```
var PbiHeader = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{this.props.releaseData.name}</td> //Here i am getting
                    undefined and i am stuck with syntax to fetch object
                    releaseData's name
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        );
    },
});
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: console.log(this.state) inside parent and let me know?

Comment: i am getting " data Object { id="-559674239450219239",  key="SW-1014",  name="Hide old Releases",  more...}  " on console

Comment: What ever syntax i change using other stack answers i get TypeError: this.props.releasedata is undefined.

Comment: just console this.props inside child component before return.Also you are using releaseData so it should be this.props.releaseData not this.props.releasedata which would be undefined obviously.

Comment: Console out --> releaseData
 Object { releaseId="508054512004262880",  name="prog rel1",  active=true,  more...}

Comment: I am using {this.props.releaseData.name} releaseData is my component attribute name in parent. i commented wrongly down

Answer (score 0):

You can use `componentWillRecieveProps` event in child component to update it's state (`componentWillRecieveProps(nextProps)`)
It's triggering when you update child props in parent component.

---

Docs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps: function(props){
  this.setState({
   name: props.releasedata.name
    });
  console.log(name);
   }, ==> TypeError: this.props.releasedata is undefined

Comment: Can you please tell me what props syntax i have to set in componentWillReceiveProps  function

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){ console.log(nextProps); } please write message from console (what in nextProps)

Answer (score 0):

To render the object properties. I set all the properties in parent setstate() itself :

**Parent Component :**

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    return { data: [],
             release: []};          ===> Defined the undefined variable type
    },
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/app/restapi/getreleasedata/"+Key+"?access_token="+accesstokenvalue+""
    }).then(function(data) {
         this.setState({data: data,
               release:data.releasedata    ===> Assign directly object from JSON to 
                                                local state variable Defined
             });
        }.bind(this))
    },
    render: function(){
    return (
        <PbiHeader pbiRelease={this.state.release.name} />   ==>Attach attribute 
                  mapping inside object properties here "name" here we can add more 
                  than one attribute eg: add release "id" "<PbiHeader pbiRelease={this.state.release.name} 
                  pbiReleaseId={this.state.release.id} .... etc />"
           )
     }
   });
```

**Child Component :**

```
var PbiHeader = React.createClass({
render: function(){
return (
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.pbiRelease}</td> //Here i mapped props to parent 
                                                    attribute name
                </tr>
              </tbody>
        )
     }
   });
```

This is how i can map to properties of an JSON nested object. If there is any other way please add on.